# Failing the test cases in printing the even-indexed and odd-indexed characters of strings

Tags: c++

Task at hand:

Given a string, S, of length N that is indexed from 0 to N-1, print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings on a single line.

The test cases are written such that The first line contains an integer, N (the number of test cases). Each line i of the N subsequent lines contain a String.

LINK TO THE QUESTION : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop/problem

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

void sum(string s1)
{

    //getting size of string
    int len;
    len=s1.length();
    //taking string values to an array
    char arr[len];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=s1[i];
    }


    //displaying the items

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
        std::cout<<(arr[i]);
    }
    std::cout<<" ";
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        if(i%2!=0)
        std::cout<<(arr[i]);
    }



}
int main() 
{

    string s1;
    std::cin>>s1;
    sum(s1);

    return 0;
}




Note:I think my code is correct , but I am failing the test cases.
```

Comment: What's your question? Does the code not compile? Not work? What inputs does it fail on?

Comment: It manually passed sample inputs like "Hacker" ,"Rank" etc but when I final submit the code it seems to fail against all test cases. Unfortunately the website does not give the test cases.

Comment: Unrelated, but `char arr[len];` is no valid C++, but a compiler-specific extension. It's also not needed at all, you can access individual chars directly like `s1[i]`.

Comment: @churill the code had compiled successfully.

Comment: Where do you read the first N? The number of test cases? You have to handle this too, I think. The input are multpile lines, not a single one. There is the problem

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Oh! but its weird, because the online compiler has by default 10 test cases.

Comment: I cannot test it, because I don't want to create an account. But the task reads like this

Comment: @RoQuOTriX I think you may be right about the fact that the input has multiple lines. kindly be patient for me to correct and run my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the correct main, if I understood the task correctly:

```
int main() 
{
    int count = 0;
    cin >> count;

    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        string s1;
        cin>>s1;
        sum(s1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes ! The compiler wants us to provide a way to allow multiple test cases at the same time. I thought it was to specify the total test cases the compiler would do and so therefore did not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

You should first take input for number of cases, Then run a loop till that number of cases, Call your function in that loop

```
int cases;
cin >> cases;
for (i = 0 to cases-1) {
    //your code in main here
}
```